# How do I get checked-in users in Eventbrite API?

Tags: jsonp, eventbrite

I'm starting a developing a custom control panel for Eventbrite

I need to get a list of all users that checked in through their "At the door" App to get a list of only people IN the event to filter people that registered but didn't assist.

I tried `event_list_attendees` but I see no parameter stating the user status and the `get_event` method says nothing about attended.

I already tried searching but I found nothing about it so I find it a little weird so if this is a known issue covered someone else, isn't possible or whatever I missed... please point me in the right direction

Thanks

Comment: When I say "checked in" users I mean checked in by any way, not only the APP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify check in status via `event_list_attendees`, you just need to include `only_display=barcodes`, etc... to your request params, you can find the status @ `/attendees/attendee/barcodes/barcode/status` in the response with values `used` or `unused` meaning if it has the status of used the ticket has been checked in and so on...

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this. What do you mean with /attendees/attendee/barcodes/barcode/status Panique/JohnBernardo?

Answer (score 3):

Right now, no "At The Door" information is available through the Eventbrite API.

It's also not possible to use the API to obtain a list of attendees who were checked in by the Eventbrite "Entry Manager" app, but you can get this information through the Eventbrite UI. Here's how:

1. Log into your Account
2. Click 'My Events' at the top of the page
3. Click the 'Completed' tab
4. Click 'Manage' to the right of the event name
5. Find the box on the left titled 'Analyze' and click the 'Event Reports' link
6. Change the Report Type drop down menu to 'Event Attendance vs No Shows'
7. Use the Check In Status drop down menu to choose 'Checked In' or 'No Shows'
8. Now you have your list of people who were checked in or did not attend. You can export this list to Excel by clicking the green File Type button

Comment: Too bad. not being able to access that data seems ridiculous, it's one of the most important fields. It was why I subscribed for the API in the first place. Thanks anyway. Regards